# Opening AdminAction in new tab, Django

Tags: django, action

I have an AdminAction that generates pdf and I would like to open it in new tab. How do I do that? 
So far I have used a redirect from that AdminAction to a url to a view function, but I can't seem to connect the view function(url) to some .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These come from the documentation on AdminAction  doest it help ?

Code to put in your admin.py

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def export_selected_objects(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    selected = queryset.values_list('pk', flat=True)
    ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(queryset.model)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/export/?ct=%s&ids=%s' % (
        ct.pk,
        ','.join(str(pk) for pk in selected),
    ))
```

And do this to activate your action once you define it :

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.add_action(export_selected_objects)
```

Comment: As far as I understood, `<a href>` provides you with a button on the page. In this case, I don't need a button, I need the new tab to be opened as part of the admin action. Also, my action requires 2 paramter inputs. And last, do you mean `target="_blank"`? Thank you!

Comment: I didn't understand it properly ! I tried to help you as much as I can with the edit of my response, all of the code and the explainations are available in the documentation on ActionAdmin